# Google Analytics API v4 how to filter only for goals > 0

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am trying to look up the goal completions for the "Ad Content" UTM paramter.  The following configuration works correctly, however, I am wanting to filter it to only return the data where GOALS > 0. It currently returns all of the data even where goals = 0.

```
return analytics.reports().batchGet(
      body={
        'reportRequests': [
        {
          'viewId': VIEW_ID,
          'dateRanges': [{'startDate': '7daysAgo', 'endDate': 'today'}],
          'metrics': [{'expression': 'ga:sessions'}, {'expression': 'ga:goalCompletionsAll'}],
          'dimensions': [{'name': 'ga:adContent'}]
        }]
      }
  ).execute()
```

Answer (score 0):

There's another parameter that you can include - 'includeEmptyRows':

```py
return analytics.reports().batchGet(
      body={
        'reportRequests': [
        {
          'viewId': VIEW_ID,
          'includeEmptyRows' : True,
          'dateRanges': [{'startDate': '7daysAgo', 'endDate': 'today'}],
          'metrics': [{'expression': 'ga:sessions'}, {'expression': 'ga:goalCompletionsAll'}],
          'dimensions': [{'name': 'ga:adContent'}]
        }]
      }
  ).execute()
```

This makes sure that the API returns dimensions even when all the values are 0.  The relevant link to the docs is here:

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/rest/v4/reports/batchGet#ReportRequest.FIELDS.include_empty_rows